# How to interpret a string as code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

How to make a function that can interpret a string as a code ?

```
var1 = 5
var2 = 10
var3 = 7

str = "(var1*var2)+var3"


result = calculate(str) # I need help to write this function
```

result should output 57

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Comment: You could use the `eval()` function which evaluates a string as code but be aware that there are security problems with this if the code is coming from an external source / being inputted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `result = eval(str)` instead of `result = calculate(str)`.

**Disclaimer**: `eval()` should be used carefully since it can execute anything passed to it. More details can be found in this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eval-in-python/).

Comment: *Please* add a  disclaimer as to why `eval` should be used with *great* care and control. `ast.literal_eval` might be a better (safer) solution.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` would not work in this case as the string is not a literal, but they should definitely add an explanation as to why `eval()` should be used carefully